# Calculate Mahonian number row n index i

Tags: algorithm, math, permutation, inversion

How can i compute the [Mahonian number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Major_index) `x`at row `n`, index `i`, without compute previous rows?

Example `n := 6, i := 2`

`row := "1 3 5 6 5 3 1"`

`x := row[i]` //5

Exists therefore an algorithmn / formula?

Comment: Perhaps see https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1197226

Comment: @stark: that answer on [math.se] provides the recursion based on the previous row, which I suppose OP already knows since the question is to compute a row *without* first computing the previous rows.

Comment: I haven't looked, but you might try looking at OEIS for this sequence -- in many cases there are some brief notes about algorithms, and at least there are references for further info.

Comment: @Robert: It's [OEIS 008302](https://oeis.org/A008302), as indicated in the [math.se] link; the recursion formula presented in that answer is also in OEIS (added by the same person, as it happens). I don't think there's a known closed form, unless it has been very recently discovered. If there is one, it isn't in OEIS either.